# Signing into ArcGIS Online for Organizations using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, authentication

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2 and a short ArcPy/Python script to sign into an ArcGIS Online for Organizations account.

I have access to two such accounts, one at each of two organisations which I'll call organisation1 and organisation2. I'm testing both accounts while sitting at my desk in organisation2.

---

It works great when I access my organisation1 account from organisation2:

```
import arcpy
portal = "https://organisation1.maps.arcgis.com"
user = "firstname"
password = "XXXX"
print("Signing into portal {0} as {1}...".format(portal,user))
arcpy.SignInToPortal(portal,user,password)
print("Signing into portal successful!")
```

This is the output from IDLE:

```
= RESTART: \\organisation2.com.au.local\<long path with 2 underscores, 1 hyphen and 1space>\SignInTest.py
Signing into portal https://organisation1.maps.arcgis.com as firstname...
Signing into portal successful!
>>>
```

---

However, when I try to access my organisation2 account from organisation2

```
import arcpy
portal = "https://organisation2.maps.arcgis.com"
user = "firstname.lastname_ORGANISATION2"
password = "XXXX"
print("Signing into portal {0} as {1}...".format(portal,user))
arcpy.SignInToPortal(portal,user,password)
print("Signing into portal successful!")
```

I get an error from IDLE:

```
= RESTART: \\organisation2.com.au.local\<long path with 2 underscores, 1 hyphen and 1space>\SignInTest.py
Signing into portal https://organisation2.maps.arcgis.com as firstname.lastname_ORGANISATION2...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \\organisation2.com.au.local\<long path with 2 underscores, 1 hyphen and 1space>\SignInTest.py, line 7, in <module>
    arcpy.SignInToPortal(portal,user,password)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 2494, in SignInToPortal
    return _SignInToPortal(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: Error signing on to https://organisation2.maps.arcgis.com/.

Message              : s

Details   : Unable to generate token.
>>>
```

I think what is causing this is the difference between the username syntax at the two organisations.

- At organisation1 I am username "firstname" (no period, no underscore)
- At organisation2 I am username "firstname.lastname_ORGANISATION2" (includes period and underscore)

I think the period (or less likely the underscore) in the username at organisation2 is not being parsed correctly by Esri's SignInToPortal code.

Is anyone able to use the test code above with an existing username that includes a period and/or an underscore to see whether my theory seems to be correct?

I am separately pursuing at organisation2 how I can "rename" my "firstname.lastname_ORGANISATION2" account to be something like "FirstnameLastnameORGANISATION2" but it is non-trivial to do that.

Comment: I've hit this error before and it was related to the case sensitivity of the username. Can you confirm the username you are entering is exactly how it appears in the Org2 AGO user list?

Comment: @Tigerwoulds I'm not an administrator so unable to confirm that but I'm about to self-answer with the successful outcome as I understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this organisation2 made a new account for me named FirstnameLastnameOrganisation2 and that worked perfectly, which suggests that the period and/or the underscore in the username was causing the problem.

My old account, and its content was then removed.  Fortunately, that content was just a few test services, so I did not have to look into transferring content between old and new accounts first.